# Cypress: Return error message from resp.body with cy.(request)

Tags: cypress, http-status-codes, http-error

## Overview

- We have a list of URLs that needs to be tested regularly
- In case of an error we want to have the status code and the error message

```
Error
Code:500 //<-- I need this
Type:PHP notice
Message:Undefined index: type //<-- And this
File:/var/www/*******.******.***/web/protected/modules/rights/controllers/AuthItemController.php
Line:1134
```

## The code

```
const action_list = require('../fixtures/action_list')

describe('URL test', () => {
    
    let response = [];
    
    it('login', () => {
        cy.login(Cypress.config('userEmail'), Cypress.config('userPass'))
    })
    
    it('check URLs and write results to file', function () {
        cy.get(action_list).each((action) => {
            cy.request({url: Cypress.config('url2') +  action, failOnStatusCode: false}).then((resp) => {
                response.push({ status: resp.status, url: Cypress.config('url2') + action , message: resp.body.message})
            })
        })
         cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/response_action.json', response)
    })
})
```

## What it does

- Outputs a list with URLs and their status codes

## What it *should* do

- Output a list with URLs, the status codes AND the error message
- The part `"message: resp.body.message"` *should* output "Message:Undefined index: type"

## What I tried

### Solution attempt 1:

- Replaced `message: resp.body.message`with `message: resp.body`
- This resulted in the script returning the whole body of the URL with the error code hidden somewhere deep inside an extremely long output:
  `<h2>Error</h2>\r\n\t\t<dl>\r\n\t\t\t<dt>Code:</dt><dd>500</dd>\r\n\t\t\t<dt>Type:</dt><dd>PHP notice</dd>\r\n\t\t\t<dt>Message:</dt><dd>Undefined index: type</dd>`

### Solution attempt 2:

- Replaced `message: resp.body.message`with `message: resp.message`
- Nothing was logged

### Solution attempt 3:

- Replaced `message: resp.body.message`with `message: resp.statusText`
- Returned the message of the HTTP code. Close, but not the message I need

```
    "url": "https://*******.******.***/index.php?r=rights/authItem/create",
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
```

### Solution attempt 4:

- Tried to log the response with `cy.log(resp)`
- Cypress' output:

```
log: Output{8}
```

**What am I missing here?** :(

Comment: Can you log this and tell me whats getting printed `cy.log(JSON.Stringify(resp.body))`

Comment: The output is over 10,000 characters long as it returns the complete code of the site plus the error message for that sub page. So I can't copy it into the answer because of the character limit.

I already used "message.body" to output the complete output into a file (see solution attempt #1). The message I am looking for is hidden somewhere deep inside these 10,000+ characters.


Can you tell me what part of the log you are interested in, so I could post that part for you. Otherwise I could probably upload the complete output as a txt file.